# Sencha Touch FormPanel submit listener not working

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I'm trying to add a listener to a Ext.form.Formpanel subelement Ext.form.BasicForm for the submit event and then reset the form via its .reset() method. In the doc at http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.form.FormPanel it clearly states that:

```
submit : ( Ext.FormPanel this, Object result ) 
Fires upon successful (Ajax-based) form submission
```

But it somehow it won't really work for me.
This is my code:

```
    var messInput = new Ext.form.FormPanel
({
    fullscreen : true,
    url : '/mess/',
    standardSubmit : false,
    listeners : {
        el: {
            submit: function(form, result) {
                form.reset();
            }
        }
            },
    items: [
            new Ext.form.Text ({
                name : 'mess',
                placeHolder: 'Text and #Tags',
                listeners : {
                keyup :function(field, event) { 
                    var keyCode = event.browserEvent.keyCode;
                    if(keyCode == 51) {
                        console.log(event.browserEvent.keyCode);
                    }

                }
            }
        })]
});
```

if i try it this way i get a

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reset'

Can somebody explain what the problem is excatly here? do i need to call the parent Formpanel because i add the listener to the underlying el?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are listening to basic js-event "submit" for the dom-element. You can't get (easily) sencha objects inside it. That's why Ext.form.FormPanel has beforeSubmit-event. The data is already collected so you can reset the form and process to ajax submit with return true;

```
form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    fullscreen : true,
    url : '/mess/',
    listeners: {
        beforesubmit: function(e, a) {
           this.reset();
           return true;
        }
    },

    standardSubmit : false,
    items: [
            new Ext.form.Text ({
                name : 'mess',
                placeHolder: 'Text and #Tags',
                listeners : {
                keyup :function(field, event) { 
                    var keyCode = event.browserEvent.keyCode;
                    if(keyCode == 51) {
                        console.log(event.browserEvent.keyCode);
                    }

                }
            }
        })]
});
```

**EDIT:** This is the correct way, sorry about the last answer.

Comment: thank you. But where is this stated in the documentation?
if i do it you way, it will reset the form-fields but also do an empty post request. Shouldn't this event fire after the form's submission?